# which fuelphp folder should I add to my own version control?

Tags: git, fuelphp

I'm using fuelphp and realised that fuelphp come with his own .git folder.

I want to use my own git repo.
I guess it's the best way when I only add the fuel folder to my vcs?
But than I lost the framework code and the composer file and some other stuff.

I'm really confused how this should work. Maybe someone can give me a point which parts are important or if there is a strategy or a good practice.
Thanks!

Comment: For clarity, did you cone fuelphp/fuelphp or fuel/fuel?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is add a new origin to your project.

```
oil create [project_name]
cd [project_name]
git remote rename origin fuelphp
git branch master
git checkout master
git remote add origin [your_git_repo_address]
git config branch.master.remote origin
git config branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
git clone --bare . [your_git_repo_address]
git push

git remote add origin [your_git_repo_address]
git push -u origin --all
git push -u origin --tags
```